# Python Matplotlib- Plotting Dictionaries in a certain order

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib for a literary analysis of all the Cantos (chapters) of the Inferno in the Divine Comedy. Most of the analysis I'm doing is for word count, particularly unique word occurrence, and I was able to split up a given text into a list of its constituent words, then convert that list to a dictionary that's ordered by the highest wordcount. Of course dictionaries aren't ordered structures, which is where I have my problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
def main():
    def read_files(foo):
        file1 = open(foo, 'r')
        # Reads the file
        read1 = file1.read()
        # This converts each character in the file to lowercase to facilitate
        # word analysis
        read1_lower = read1.lower()

         # This converts the read into a list, splitting it by spaces
        list1 = list(read1_lower.split(' '))

        # Uses the counter from collections to order the list in dictionary format
        x = Counter(list1)
        print x
        # Makes a bar plot using matplotlib  
        plt.bar(range(len(x)), x.values(), align='center')
        plt.xticks(range(len(x)), x.keys())

        plt.show()
        print 'Canto I:'
        read_files('CantoI.txt')
main()
```

The first Canto is used as an example here. When x is printed it generates a nice dictionary:

```
>>> 
Canto I:
"Counter({'the': 57, 'and': 43, 'i': 36, 'that': 31, 'to': 24, 'of': 20,     
'me': 19, 'thou': 19, 'was': 16, 'he': 16, 'so': 15, 'which': 14, 'a': 13, 
'with': 13, 'my': 11, 'her': 11,..."
```

and so on and so forth. It's still possible to plot this counter, but when it's plotted every word is plotted, and the overall plot is far too compressed to be of any use.

So here's my question: it'd be a lot more useful to generate a bar graph for, say, the top ten words in the dictionary. Is there a way I can indicate that in the 'range' section of the plt.bar and plt.xticks, despite the dictionary not being inherently ordered?

Answer (score 0):

Python's [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: The OrderedDict worked out well, and now they're ordered. It now it looks like this:   OrderedDict([('the', 57), ('and', 43), ('i', 36), ('that', 31), ('to', 24), ('of', 20), ('me', 19), ('thou', 19), ('was', 16), ('he', 16), ('so', 15), ('which', 14), ('a', 13)...

Comment: I just need some manner in which I can select a specific number of those sublists (the first ten, for instance) so I can use them in the bar chart

Comment: The .items() on the ordered dict can be sliced like any other list. For example: d = OrderedDict([('the', 57), ('and', 43)]),d.items()[:10])